# UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't fire after rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got a `TabBarController` which has two tabs. In each tab I've got `UICollectionView` and `UITapGestureRecognizer` which fires every time when I tap on `collectionView`. Everything works fine after the app is started. But if I rotate to landscape orientation, `TapGestureRecognizer` fires only in the `collectionView`'s old frame. It absolutely ignores  the right side of the screen.

But if I switch to another tab and then back, it'll work fine for landscape orientation too. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

That's how I change orientation mode for `collectionView`:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self.cardCollectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```

Comment: check the size of parent view after rotation.

Comment: size of parent view is correct after rotation and still the recogniser works only in frame which was before rotation. And it starts working properly right after I switch to another tab and come back.

Comment: I have a same problem. After rotation, TapGestureRecognizer does not work if the device is portrait orientation. it works if the device is landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

invalidateLayout doesn't actually invalidate layout of collection view itself, it force invalidation and recalculating of internal cell layout - [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionViewLayout/invalidateLayout)

To handle collection view frame changes you have to think about it like about regular view. Try to set autoresizing mask of your collection view (for example in viewDidLoad) like:

```
self.cardCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

### UPDATE

try to set autoresizing for your collection view to http://d.pr/i/nk3o, by code it will looks like:

```
self.cardCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|
```

;

**UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin** is important to say UIKit from where calculate position

Comment: After I change orientation, I see that collectionViewCelles has been drown fine and filled all collectionView, but tapRecognizer does't fire. I've tried your solution, but it's doesn't work either.

Comment: try to set backgroundColor of your collectionView to something like [UIColor redColor] and see what is actual frame of collection view - is it correct after rotation?

Comment: I did it and size of collection view is correct, but still have the problem with firing tapGesture

Comment: how do you add gesture? do you remove invalidateLayout?

Comment: I add gesture though interface. Now, properties of UITapGestureRecognizer looks like [this](http://ge.tt/1ldrW301/v/0?c) and also I cleared my method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` still rotates fine, but recogniser doesn't work right after launch, only after I change tabs.

Comment: try to add gesture in code, like UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(flipCard:)]; [self.cardCollectionView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

Comment: Added that code in viewDidLoad. Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Still have the same effect. Tap recognises only in old frame's after rotation and works right right after I change tabs and get back to previous.